# The remainder when $a+qn$ is divided by $n$ is equal to the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ where $a,q,n$ are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can't think of a way to prove this, what I've done so far is take the remainder of $a+qn$ when divided by $n$ again, but is there a better way?

Comment: How are you defining a remainder?

Comment: Are you asking why $a+qn \equiv a \pmod{n}$?

Comment: the remainder is more than or equal to 0 and less than n, and yes to Paolo Leonetti

Answer (score 0):

I take it by remainder you mean the part not wholly divisible by n.

Consider that

$$\frac{a + qn}{n} = \frac{a}{n} + q$$

Hence any remainder is determined by the remaining part after wholly dividing $a$ by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $a+qn=r_1+q_1n$ and $a=r_2+q_2n$, where $r_1,q_1,r_2,q_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le r_1,r_2 < n$, then 
$$qn = (a+qn)-a = (r_1-r_2)+(q_1-q_2)n.$$
Then $n|r_1-r_2$. But $-n < r_1-r_2 < n$, so $r_1=r_2$. Therefore $a$ and $a+qn$ have the same remainder.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:**

Let $a=qn+r$

where *q* is the quotient and *r* is the remainder. This implies that:

$a \equiv r\mod n $ $\hspace{10cm}$ **(1)**

Looking at $a+qn$ , it follows that: $\hspace{1cm}$*(since $qn \equiv 0 \mod n$)* $\hspace{2.1cm}$

$a+qn \equiv a \equiv r \mod n $ $\hspace{8.1cm}$ **(2)**

Thus the remainder is $r$ in both **(1)** and **(2)** and we are done.

*Source:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ are integers, with $y\ne0$, it can be proved that there exist *unique* integers $p$ and $r$ such that
$$
x=py+r\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le r<|y|
$$
Thus we can speak of *the* remainder $r$ and *the* quotient $p$.

Now if we divide $a$ by $n$, we have $a=pn+r$ with $0\le r<|n|$. Since
$$
a+qn=(p+q)n+r
$$
we see that $p+q$ and $r$ satisfy the requirements for being the quotient and the remainder of the division of $a+qn$ by $n$. So $r$ *is* the remainder of the division of $a+qn$ by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, $ The remainder of $\,a\div n\,$ is the least natural in $\,a+n\Bbb Z$

But $\ a\!+\!nq+n\Bbb Z = a+n(\color{#c00}{q+\Bbb Z}) = a+n\color{#c00}{\Bbb Z},\ $ so it has the same least natural.